# Check Authentication Mode of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

Before changing SQL server authentication mode to mixed mode, I need to check whether it has already mixed mode or only windows authentication mode.

How can I check whether the server has mixed mode or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In registry on the server is a key which show the authentication mode . You can check registry key or exec this :

```
Exec xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode'
```

value 2 is mixed mode and 1 is windows mode

Comment: Have a very very great thanks @Amir, It works for me pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Using xp_instance_regread system procedure, we can read the registry value

```
DECLARE @AuthenticationMode INT  
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',   
N'LoginMode', @AuthenticationMode OUTPUT  

SELECT CASE @AuthenticationMode    
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 2 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
ELSE 'Unknown'  
END as [Authentication Mode]
```

OR

you can query registry

```
DECLARE @LoginMode int
EXEC master..xp_regread 
     @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
     @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\', 
     @value_name = 'LoginMode',
     @value = @LoginMode output
PRINT @LoginMode
```

1= SQL
2= Mixed mode

Comment: When posting code, please highlight the block and hit the `{}` button. It keeps the formatting and turns on syntax highlighting.