# How to enable sa login when doing an unattended install of SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an installer that's running the SQL Server 2014 Express installer in unattended mode.

Basically, it's creating a command-line and running the setup.

My problem is that I need to be able to connect to the installed instance as admin using SQL Server authentication.

The command-line already contains `/SECURITY MODE=SQL`. I can create a SQL login and login successfully, so that part of the problem works fine.

My problem is that while I can see `sa` in `sys.server_principals`, it's flagged as `is_disabled`, and I can't login using it.

Is there a way, when running the SQL Server 2014 install unattended, to pass command line arguments that will have it enable `sa` so I can successfully login using it?

Or some other login, if that's easier.

What I need is a `sql_login` that I can use to connect to the database as an db administrator without regard for the permissions of the logged-in windows user, after having run the installer in unattended mode.

The full commandline args:

```
/QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL 
    /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SAPWD="SQLSVCPASSWORD"
```

If I login to Windows using an admin account, I can connect to the database using Windows authentication. I can then create a normal SQL Server login. With that, I can then login using SQL Server authentication and that account.

So I'm certain the DB is in mixed mode. And this:

```
Exec xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode'
```

returns '2'.

My problem is that I need the users to be able to run the software without being a windows admin. And part of what the software needs to be able to do is to drop and create databases, within the instance.

So I need SQL admin permissions, without depending upon the windows user having elevated permissions.

===

The setup tool I'm using is configured using XML files that contain, in them, LUA scripts that build and run the Windows Installer package command lines. Between the nested languages and various levels of escaping, I'd not noticed that the "/SECURITYMODE=SQL" argument was commented out, and not included in the command line.

With it included in the command line, the "sa" user is enabled.

**TL;RD** If you want the "sa" user enabled, after an install, include "/SECURITYMODE=SQL" on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `/SAPWD` as well when using `/SECURITYMODE=SQL`. I am not sure, but if you do not specify the password, it will be disabled by default.

Have a look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017 for more information.

Comment: I am specifying "SAPWD='StrongPassword'. The sa login is still disabled.

Comment: Can you actually see that the security is set to mixed mode or windows authentication in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Yes. I can connect using windows authentication, and while connected I can create sql logins, and can then connect using those sql logins.

Comment: OK, but if you right click on server and choose properties, can you see on the Security page under Server authentication that Mixed Mode is used?

Comment: I can't install SSMS on the laptops that this needs to run on.

Comment: Have a look at this link for checking with TSQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869898/check-authentication-mode-of-sql-server

Comment: BTW. In the command line above that you specified, there is no `/SECURITYMODE=SQL`

Comment: Yep. Thanks for noticing. There's a line in the script, but it's been commented out. That may fix it.